# Some problems with netbeans 6.9 for PHP - bug or not?

Tags: ide, netbeans

Just downloaded and installed netbeans 6.9. At the first run, it asked for importing settings from netbeans 6.8 (which is nice). But after using it for my current PHP project for a while, I found this new version sucks. Here are some problem:

- "Refactor->Rename" always gives me "The Rename Refactoring cannot be applied
  in this context". If I press the Ctrl+R, the whole IDE halt!
- Most of the time it shows "Checking for external changes" in the status bar.
- Some plug-ins that exist in version 6.8 are not available in version 6.9

Anyone encounters the same problems and know how to deal with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running 64bit Netbeans (PHP) on a Mac.

Yes to number 1. Selected from the menu and keyboard.
No to number 2. It does state that once in a while (as in rarely).. though that might depend on the project really.

Number 3; which plugins you looking for?

Comment: Thx Stephen! Don't know why the development team didn't find such a common issue. Renaming is very useful feature. 

For No.2, it does happen for large projects only. The IDE scans external changes very frequently. And it is much slower than version 6.8.

But I really think that for PHP, the new formatter and "Overridden/Implemented" annotations in version 6.9 can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I've got all the issues you wrote about. I had to split my project into 3 different projects just to make it work reasonably fast (too many files kills 6.9 apparently).

Also, the auto-formatter sucks. Half of the options don't work at all.

And who thought it would be a good idea to add a spell checker to a *&^(%*£ code editor?!?!?! Worst. Idea. EVER.

I've been using Eclipse for the last 2 days.

+1 to version 6.9 being total trash.

Comment: I switched back to version 6.8 though. I just use v6.9 to format code written by others. I agree that the formatter sucks, but it is still better than that in v6.8. One good thing of netbeans is that, it ships with many useful tools for web development. While in Eclipse PDT (or even aptana studio), it needs a lot of customization and configuration to get that.